# Computer shutdown during use

Tags: reboot

During use, being it intensive or not (just typing text for example) my computer sometimes "shutdown".

Both screens went black and display the "no signal" message. The computer case still show lights lit, but no keyboard response, no reset button response. I need to cut power and turn it on again.

Any ideas how to diagnose the problem?

Computer specs:
CPU Intel i7 860
Motherboard intel DH55TC
4 gb ram DDR3
NVDIA Geforce GT240
HD 1 tb 
Windows 7 64
SPU specs (it is in portguese, so a direct translation): Combined nominal power: 400W

Output from HW monitor right now:

### CPUID HWMonitor Report

### Binaries

HWMonitor version   1.1.8.0

### Monitoring

Mainboard Model     DH55TC (0x0000018D - 0x00574060)

### LPCIO

LPCIO Vendor        Winbond
LPCIO Model     W83627DHG-P
LPCIO Vendor ID     0x5CA3
LPCIO Chip ID       0xB0
LPCIO Revision ID   0x73
Config Mode I/O address 0x2E
Config Mode LDN     0xB
Config Mode registers
        00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 
    00  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 0B FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    10  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    20  B0 73 58 00 44 00 00 FF 50 42 00 00 92 21 00 FF 
    30  01 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    40  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    50  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    60  0A 10 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
    70  00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
Register space      LPC, base address = 0x0A10

### Hardware Monitors

Hardware monitor    Winbond W83627DHG
    Voltage 0   0.87 Volts [0x6D] (CPU VCORE)
    Voltage 1   0.76 Volts [0x5F] (VIN1)
    Voltage 2   3.44 Volts [0xD7] (+3.3V)
    Voltage 3   5.16 Volts [0xD7] (+5V)
    Voltage 4   9.09 Volts [0xA3] (+12V)
    Voltage 5   0.76 Volts [0x5F] (VIN5)
    Voltage 6   1.06 Volts [0x84] (VIN6)
    Temperature 0   40°C (104°F) [0x28] (SYSTIN)
    Temperature 1   43°C (109°F) [0x56] (CPUTIN)
Hardware registers
Register space      LPC, base address = 0x0A10
bank 0
        00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 
    00  04 FF 04 7F 01 00 32 20 01 80 01 01 3C 3C 0A 0A 
    10  04 FF 10 00 00 01 01 3C 43 37 00 00 29 FF FF C3 
    20  6D 5F D7 D7 A3 5F 84 28 FF FF FF DA 00 06 E5 FF 
    30  AC AE DE FB 61 6D DA EE 96 6E BF BD E1 F7 BE FF 
    40  03 00 00 FF FF 00 3F F5 2D 00 00 C4 10 95 00 A3 
    50  FF FF 00 FF FF FF 00 80 C1 70 FF FF 19 E6 06 05 
    60  04 7F 40 00 01 01 3C FF 01 FF 01 FF FF FF FF 00 
    70  00 00 00 00 00 0E 7F 7F 7F 7F 7F 7F 00 28 FF FF 
    80  04 FF 04 7F 01 00 32 20 01 80 01 01 3C 3C 0A 0A 
    90  04 FF 10 00 00 01 01 3C 43 37 00 00 29 FF FF C3 
    A0  6D 5F D7 D7 A3 5F 84 28 FF FF FF DA 00 06 E5 FF 
    B0  AC AE DE FB 61 6D DA EE 96 6E BF BD E1 F7 BE FF 
    C0  03 00 00 FF FF 00 3F F5 2D 00 00 C4 10 95 00 A3 
    D0  FF FF 00 FF FF FF 00 80 C1 70 FF FF 19 E6 06 05 
    E0  04 7F 40 00 01 01 3C FF 01 FF 01 FF FF FF FF 00 
    F0  00 00 00 00 00 0E 7F 7F 7F 7F 7F 7F 00 28 FF FF 
bank 1
    50  2B 80 00 4B 00 50 10 8A 00 00 00 00 00 00 0E FF 
bank 2
    50  7F 00 00 4B 00 50 0B 6A FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
bank 3
    50  04 01 06 06 02 03 03 05 00 00 25 65 25 0B 00 00 
bank 4
    50  00 13 FF 00 00 00 00 09 2F CA 3C BB 09 60 20 7F

Hardware monitor    HECI version 6.0.0.49B
    Voltage 1   11.91 Volts [0x2E82] (+12V)
    Voltage 3   5.03 Volts [0x13A7] (+5V)
    Voltage 6   3.36 Volts [0xD21] (+3.3V)
    Voltage 8   1.52 Volts [0x5EC] (+1.5V)
    Voltage 9   0.86 Volts [0x35A] (CPU1 VCCP)
    Temperature 2   41°C (105°F) [0x29] (CPU Die)
    Temperature 5   49°C (120°F) [0x31] (Voltage Reg.)
    Temperature 6   40°C (104°F) [0x28] (Memory)
    Temperature 18  59°C (138°F) [0x3B] (PCH)
    Fan 1       1006 RPM [0x3EE] (CPU)
Register space      class = 0x15

Hardware monitor    NVIDIA NVAPI
    Voltage 0   1.00 Volts [0x3E8] (VIN0)
    Temperature 0   40°C (104°F) [0x28] (TMPIN0)
    Fan PWM 0   10 pc [0xA] (FANPWMIN0)

### Processors

Number of processors        1
Number of threads       8

### APICs

Processor 0 
    -- Core 0
        -- Thread 0 0
        -- Thread 1 1
    -- Core 1
        -- Thread 0 2
        -- Thread 1 3
    -- Core 2
        -- Thread 0 4
        -- Thread 1 5
    -- Core 3
        -- Thread 0 6
        -- Thread 1 7

### Processors Information

Processor 1         ID = 0
    Number of cores     4 (max 8)
    Number of threads   8 (max 16)
    Name            Intel Core i7 860
    Codename        Lynnfield
    Specification       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU         860  @ 2.80GHz
    Package (platform ID)   Socket 1156 LGA (0x1)
    CPUID           6.E.5
    Extended CPUID      6.1E
    Core Stepping       B1
    Technology      45 nm
    TDP Limit       95 Watts
    Core Speed      1197.0 MHz
    Multiplier x FSB    9.0 x 133.0 MHz
    Rated Bus speed     2394.0 MHz
    Stock frequency     2800 MHz
    Instructions sets   MMX, SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2, EM64T, VT-x
    L1 Data cache       4 x 32 KBytes, 8-way set associative, 64-byte line size
    L1 Instruction cache    4 x 32 KBytes, 4-way set associative, 64-byte line size
    L2 cache        4 x 256 KBytes, 8-way set associative, 64-byte line size
    L3 cache        8 MBytes, 16-way set associative, 64-byte line size
    FID/VID Control     yes

```
Turbo Mode      supported, enabled
Max turbo frequency 3466 MHz
Max non-turbo ratio 21x
Max turbo ratio     26x
Max efficiency ratio    9x
TDC Limit       89 Amps
Core TDP        89 Watts
Uncore TDP      6 Watts
Power @ 9x      13 Watts
Power @ 10x     15 Watts
Power @ 11x     18 Watts
Power @ 12x     22 Watts
Power @ 13x     27 Watts
Power @ 14x     32 Watts
Power @ 15x     38 Watts
Power @ 16x     45 Watts
Power @ 17x     53 Watts
Power @ 18x     62 Watts
Power @ 19x     71 Watts
Power @ 20x     82 Watts
Power @ 21x     95 Watts
Max bus number      63
Attached device     PCI device at bus 63, device 2, function 1
Attached device     PCI device at bus 63, device 3, function 4
Attached device     PCI device at bus 63, device 2, function 1
```

### Thread dumps

CPU Thread 0
    APIC ID         0
    Topology        Processor ID 0, Core ID 0, Thread ID 0
    Type            01020001h
    Max CPUID level     0000000Bh
    Max CPUID ext. level    80000008h
    Cache descriptor    Level 1, D, 32 KB, 2 thread(s)
    Cache descriptor    Level 1, I, 32 KB, 2 thread(s)
    Cache descriptor    Level 2, U, 256 KB, 2 thread(s)
    Cache descriptor    Level 3, U, 8 MB, 16 thread(s)

CPU Thread 1
    APIC ID         1
    Topology        Processor ID 0, Core ID 0, Thread ID 1
    Type            01020001h
    Max CPUID level     0000000Bh
    Max CPUID ext. level    80000008h
    Cache descriptor    Level 1, D, 32 KB, 2 thread(s)
    Cache descriptor    Level 1, I, 32 KB, 2 thread(s)
    Cache descriptor    Level 2, U, 256 KB, 2 thread(s)
    Cache descriptor    Level 3, U, 8 MB, 16 thread(s)

CPU Thread 2
    APIC ID         2
    Topology        Processor ID 0, Core ID 1, Thread ID 0
    Type            01020001h
    Max CPUID level     0000000Bh
    Max CPUID ext. level    80000008h
    Cache descriptor    Level 1, D, 32 KB, 2 thread(s)
    Cache descriptor    Level 1, I, 32 KB, 2 thread(s)
    Cache descriptor    Level 2, U, 256 KB, 2 thread(s)
    Cache descriptor    Level 3, U, 8 MB, 16 thread(s)

CPU Thread 3
    APIC ID         3
    Topology        Processor ID 0, Core ID 1, Thread ID 1
    Type            01020001h
    Max CPUID level     0000000Bh
    Max CPUID ext. level    80000008h
    Cache descriptor    Level 1, D, 32 KB, 2 thread(s)
    Cache descriptor    Level 1, I, 32 KB, 2 thread(s)
    Cache descriptor    Level 2, U, 256 KB, 2 thread(s)
    Cache descriptor    Level 3, U, 8 MB, 16 thread(s)

CPU Thread 4
    APIC ID         4
    Topology        Processor ID 0, Core ID 2, Thread ID 0
    Type            01020001h
    Max CPUID level     0000000Bh
    Max CPUID ext. level    80000008h
    Cache descriptor    Level 1, D, 32 KB, 2 thread(s)
    Cache descriptor    Level 1, I, 32 KB, 2 thread(s)
    Cache descriptor    Level 2, U, 256 KB, 2 thread(s)
    Cache descriptor    Level 3, U, 8 MB, 16 thread(s)

CPU Thread 5
    APIC ID         5
    Topology        Processor ID 0, Core ID 2, Thread ID 1
    Type            01020001h
    Max CPUID level     0000000Bh
    Max CPUID ext. level    80000008h
    Cache descriptor    Level 1, D, 32 KB, 2 thread(s)
    Cache descriptor    Level 1, I, 32 KB, 2 thread(s)
    Cache descriptor    Level 2, U, 256 KB, 2 thread(s)
    Cache descriptor    Level 3, U, 8 MB, 16 thread(s)

CPU Thread 6
    APIC ID         6
    Topology        Processor ID 0, Core ID 3, Thread ID 0
    Type            01020001h
    Max CPUID level     0000000Bh
    Max CPUID ext. level    80000008h
    Cache descriptor    Level 1, D, 32 KB, 2 thread(s)
    Cache descriptor    Level 1, I, 32 KB, 2 thread(s)
    Cache descriptor    Level 2, U, 256 KB, 2 thread(s)
    Cache descriptor    Level 3, U, 8 MB, 16 thread(s)

CPU Thread 7
    APIC ID         7
    Topology        Processor ID 0, Core ID 3, Thread ID 1
    Type            01020001h
    Max CPUID level     0000000Bh
    Max CPUID ext. level    80000008h
    Cache descriptor    Level 1, D, 32 KB, 2 thread(s)
    Cache descriptor    Level 1, I, 32 KB, 2 thread(s)
    Cache descriptor    Level 2, U, 256 KB, 2 thread(s)
    Cache descriptor    Level 3, U, 8 MB, 16 thread(s)

### Storage

USB Device          Generic USB Hub, class=0x09, subclass=0x00, vendor=0x8087, product=0x0020
USB Device          Microsoft Hardware USB Mouse, class=0x00, subclass=0x00, vendor=0x045E, product=0x00CB
USB Device          USB Input Device, class=0x00, subclass=0x00, vendor=0x04CA, product=0x0022
USB Device          Generic USB Hub, class=0x09, subclass=0x00, vendor=0x8087, product=0x0020

### Graphic APIs

API             NVIDIA I/O
API             NVIDIA NVAPI

### Display Adapters

Display adapter 0
    Name            NVIDIA GeForce GT 240
    Revision        A2
    Codename        GT215
    Technology      40 nm
    PCI device      bus 1 (0x1), device 0 (0x0), function 0 (0x0)
    Vendor ID       0x10DE (0x1ACC)
    Model ID        0x0CA3 (0x30D3)

### ACPI

ACPI Tree
_GPE
  _L07
  _L1B
  _L09
  _L03
  _L04
  _L0C
  _L0E
  _L05
  _L20
  _L25
  _L06
  _L08
  _L0B
  _L0D
*PR*
  SSDT
  CSDT
  NCST
  NPSS
  HNDL
  CHDL
  TNLP
  CINT
  PDCV
  APSS
  PTCI
  TSSI
  TSSM
  C1ST
  CMST
  CIST
  CST_
  PDC_
  OSC_
  P000
    _PDC
    _OSC
    _PCT
    _PSS
    _PPC
    _PSD
    _TPC
    _PTC
    _TSS
    _CST
  P001
    _PDC
    _OSC
    _PCT
    _PSS
    _PPC
    _PSD
    _TPC
    _PTC
    _TSS
    _CST
  P002
    _PDC
    _OSC
    _PCT
    _PSS
    _PPC
    _PSD
    _TPC
    _PTC
    _TSS
    _CST
  P003
    _PDC
    _OSC
    _PCT
    _PSS
    _PPC
    _PSD
    _TPC
    _PTC
    _TSS
    _CST
  P004
    _PDC
    _OSC
    _PCT
    _PSS
    _PPC
    _PSD
    _TPC
    _PTC
    _TSS
    _CST
  P005
    _PDC
    _OSC
    _PCT
    _PSS
    _PPC
    _PSD
    _TPC
    _PTC
    _TSS
    _CST
  P006
    _PDC
    _OSC
    _PCT
    _PSS
    _PPC
    _PSD
    _TPC
    _PTC
    _TSS
    _CST
  P007
    _PDC
    _OSC
    _PCT
    _PSS
    _PPC
    _PSD
    _TPC
    _PTC
    _TSS
    _CST
*SB*
  PR00
  AR00
  PR20
  AR20
  PR11
  AR11
  PR15
  AR15
  PR16
  AR16
  PRSA
  PRSB
  PRSC
  PRSD
  PRSE
  PRSF
  PRSG
  PRSH
  PCI0
    _HID
    _CID
    _ADR
    _BBN
    _UID
    _PRT
    *S3D
    MCH*
      _HID
      _UID
      MCHR
      _CRS
    NPTS
    NWAK
    P0P1
      _ADR
      _PRW
    P0P2
      _ADR
      _PRW
    P0P3
      _ADR
      _PRW
    P0P4
      _ADR
      _PRW
    P0P5
      _ADR
      _PRW
    SBRG
      _ADR
      SPTS
      SWAK
      SBPA
      [ ]
      [ ]
      CADR
      [ ]
      CBDR
      [ ]
      LPTD
      [ ]
      FDDD
      [ ]
      CADE
      CBDE
      LPDE
      FDDE
      RRIO
      RDMA
      APMP
      [ ]
      APMC
      APMS
      [ ]
      [ ]
      [ ]
      BRTC
      SMIE
      [ ]
      [ ]
      PS1E
      [ ]
      PS1S
      [ ]
      SIO1
        _HID
        *UID
        CRS*
        *CRS
        DCAT
        MUT0
        ENFG
        EXFG
        LPTM
        UHID
        IOID
        [ ]
        INDX
        DATA
        [ ]
        [ ]
        LDN*
        [ ]
        OP2C
        OP2D
        [ ]
        ACTR
        [ ]
        IOAH
        IOAL
        IOH2
        IOL2
        [ ]
        INTR
        [ ]
        DMCH
        [ ]
        RGE0
        RGE1
        RGE2
        RGE3
        RGE4
        RGE5
        RGE6
        RGE7
        [ ]
        OPT0
        OPT1
        OPT2
        OPT3
        OPT4
        OPT5
        OPT6
        OPT7
        OPT8
        OPT9
        CGLD
        DSTA
        DCNT
        CRS1
        IRQM
        DMAM
        IO11
        IO12
        LEN1
        CRS2
        IRQE
        DMAE
        IO21
        IO22
        LEN2
        IO31
        IO32
        LEN3
        DCRS
        DSRS
      PMFG
      SIOS
      SIOW
      SIOH
      IOKP
      [ ]
      KP60
      [ ]
      KP64
      KB64
      [ ]
      [ ]
      KRDY
      [ ]
      AY34
      [ ]
      G549
      IOKS
      IOKW
      IOKH
      UAR1
        _UID
        _HID
        _STA
        _DIS
        _CRS
        _SRS
        _PRS
        _PRW
      LPTE
        _HID
        _STA
        _DIS
        _CRS
        _SRS
        *PRS
        LPPR
        EPPR
      PIC*
        _HID
        _CRS
      DMAD
        _HID
        *CRS
      TMR*
        _HID
        _CRS
      RTC0
        _HID
        _CRS
      SPKR
        _HID
        _CRS
      RMSC
        _HID
        *UID
        CRS*
        _CRS
      COPR
        _HID
        _CRS
      PS2K
        _HID
        _CID
        _STA
        _CRS
        _PRS
        _PSW
        _PRW
      PS2M
        _HID
        _CID
        _STA
        CRS1
        CRS2
        _CRS
        _PRS
        _PSW
        *PRW
      PIX0
    PCH*
      _HID
      _UID
      _STA
      ICHR
      _CRS
    SAT0
      _ADR
      REGF
      _REG
      TIM0
      TMD0
      PIO0
      DMA0
      PIO1
      DMA1
      CHNF
      CFG2
      [ ]
      PMPT
      PSPT
      PMRI
      [ ]
      SMPT
      SSPT
      SMRI
      [ ]
      PSRI
      SSRI
      [ ]
      PM3E
      PS3E
      SM3E
      SS3E
      [ ]
      PMUT
      [ ]
      PSUT
      [ ]
      SMUT
      [ ]
      SSUT
      [ ]
      [ ]
      PM6E
      PS6E
      SM6E
      SS6E
      PMCR
      PSCR
      SMCR
      SSCR
      [ ]
      PMAE
      PSAE
      SMAE
      SSAE
      GMPT
      GMUE
      GMUT
      GMCR
      GSPT
      GSUE
      GSUT
      GSCR
      CHN0
        _ADR
        _GTM
        _STM
        DRV0
          _ADR
          _GTF
        DRV1
          _ADR
          _GTF
      CHN1
        _ADR
        _GTM
        _STM
        DRV0
          _ADR
          _GTF
        DRV1
          _ADR
          *GTF
      GTM*
      STM_
      AT01
      AT02
      AT03
      AT04
      ATA0
      ATA1
      ATA2
      ATA3
      ATAB
      CMDC
      GTFB
      GTF_
      RATA
    NATA
    SAT1
      _ADR
      REGF
      _REG
      TIM0
      TMD0
      PIO0
      DMA0
      PIO1
      DMA1
      CHNF
      CFG2
      [ ]
      PMPT
      PSPT
      PMRI
      [ ]
      SMPT
      SSPT
      SMRI
      [ ]
      PSRI
      SSRI
      [ ]
      PM3E
      PS3E
      SM3E
      SS3E
      [ ]
      PMUT
      [ ]
      PSUT
      [ ]
      SMUT
      [ ]
      SSUT
      [ ]
      [ ]
      PM6E
      PS6E
      SM6E
      SS6E
      PMCR
      PSCR
      SMCR
      SSCR
      [ ]
      PMAE
      PSAE
      SMAE
      SSAE
      GMPT
      GMUE
      GMUT
      GMCR
      GSPT
      GSUE
      GSUT
      GSCR
      CHN0
        _ADR
        _GTM
        _STM
        DRV0
          _ADR
          _GTF
        DRV1
          _ADR
          _GTF
      CHN1
        _ADR
        _GTM
        _STM
        DRV0
          _ADR
          _GTF
        DRV1
          _ADR
          *GTF
      GTM*
      STM_
      AT01
      AT02
      AT03
      AT04
      ATA0
      ATA1
      ATA2
      ATA3
      ATAB
      CMDC
      GTFB
      GTF_
      RATA
    SMB_
      _ADR
      SMIO
      [ ]
      HSTS
      HCNT
      HCMD
      TSAD
      HDT0
      HDT1
      HBDT
      RSAD
      RSDA
      AUST
      AUCT
      SMLP
      SMBP
      SSTS
      SCMD
      NDAD
      NDLB
      NDHB
      SMCS
    PEX0
      *ADR
      PXRC
      [ ]
      [ ]
      [ ]
      PMS*
      PMP_
      [ ]
      [ ]
      HPE_
      PCE_
      [ ]
      HPS_
      PCS_
      CSS_
      SPRT
      WPRT
      _PRW
      _PRT
    PEX4
      *ADR
      PXRC
      [ ]
      [ ]
      [ ]
      PMS*
      PMP_
      [ ]
      [ ]
      HPE_
      PCE_
      [ ]
      HPS_
      PCS_
      CSS_
      SPRT
      WPRT
      _PRW
      _PRT
    PEX5
      *ADR
      PXRC
      [ ]
      [ ]
      [ ]
      PMS*
      PMP_
      [ ]
      [ ]
      HPE_
      PCE_
      [ ]
      HPS_
      PCS_
      CSS_
      SPRT
      WPRT
      _PRW
      *PRT
    GBE*
      _ADR
      GCNT
      *PRW
      BBBB
      [ ]
      PWST
      [ ]
      DSC*
      GBES
      [ ]
      MSIE
      _STA
    BR20
      _ADR
      _PRT
      _PRW
    EUSB
      _ADR
      R82H
      [ ]
      [ ]
      WABT
      [ ]
      _S4D
      _S3D
      _S2D
      _S1D
      EPTS
      EWAK
      HUBN
        _ADR
        PR01
          _ADR
          _UPC
          _PLD
          PR11
            _ADR
            _UPC
            _PLD
          PR12
            _ADR
            _UPC
            _PLD
          PR13
            _ADR
            _UPC
            _PLD
          PR14
            _ADR
            _UPC
            _PLD
          PR15
            _ADR
            _UPC
            _PLD
          PR16
            _ADR
            _UPC
            _PLD
          PR17
            _ADR
            _UPC
            _PLD
          PR18
            _ADR
            _UPC
            _PLD
        PR02
          _ADR
          _UPC
          _PLD
        PR03
          _ADR
          _UPC
          _PLD
      _STA
      _PRW
    HUSB
      _ADR
      R82H
      [ ]
      [ ]
      WABT
      [ ]
      _S4D
      _S3D
      _S2D
      _S1D
      EPTS
      EWAK
      HUBN
        _ADR
        PR01
          _ADR
          _UPC
          _PLD
          PR11
            _ADR
            _UPC
            _PLD
          PR12
            _ADR
            _UPC
            _PLD
          PR13
            _ADR
            _UPC
            _PLD
          PR14
            _ADR
            _UPC
            _PLD
          PR15
            _ADR
            _UPC
            _PLD
          PR16
            _ADR
            _UPC
            _PLD
          PR17
            _ADR
            _UPC
            _PLD
          PR18
            _ADR
            _UPC
            _PLD
        PR02
          _ADR
          _UPC
          _PLD
        PR03
          _ADR
          _UPC
          _PLD
      _STA
      _PRW
    USBE
      _ADR
      R82H
      [ ]
      [ ]
      WABT
      [ ]
      _S4D
      _S3D
      _S2D
      _S1D
      EPTS
      EWAK
      HUBN
        _ADR
        PR01
          _ADR
          _UPC
          _PLD
          PR11
            _ADR
            _UPC
            _PLD
          PR12
            _ADR
            _UPC
            _PLD
          PR13
            _ADR
            _UPC
            _PLD
          PR14
            _ADR
            _UPC
            _PLD
          PR15
            _ADR
            _UPC
            _PLD
          PR16
            _ADR
            _UPC
            _PLD
          PR17
            _ADR
            _UPC
            _PLD
          PR18
            _ADR
            _UPC
            _PLD
        PR02
          _ADR
          _UPC
          _PLD
        PR03
          _ADR
          _UPC
          _PLD
      _STA
      _PRW
    USBH
      _ADR
      R82H
      [ ]
      [ ]
      WABT
      [ ]
      _S4D
      _S3D
      _S2D
      _S1D
      EPTS
      EWAK
      HUBN
        _ADR
        PR01
          _ADR
          _UPC
          _PLD
          PR11
            _ADR
            _UPC
            _PLD
          PR12
            _ADR
            _UPC
            _PLD
          PR13
            _ADR
            _UPC
            _PLD
          PR14
            _ADR
            _UPC
            _PLD
          PR15
            _ADR
            _UPC
            _PLD
          PR16
            _ADR
            _UPC
            _PLD
          PR17
            _ADR
            _UPC
            _PLD
          PR18
            _ADR
            _UPC
            _PLD
        PR02
          _ADR
          _UPC
          _PLD
        PR03
          _ADR
          _UPC
          _PLD
      _STA
      _PRW
    USB0
      _ADR
      BAR0
      [ ]
      USBW
      [ ]
      _S4D
      _S3D
      _S2D
      _S1D
      _PSW
      _PRW
      _STA
    USB1
      _ADR
      BAR0
      [ ]
      USBW
      [ ]
      _S4D
      _S3D
      _S2D
      _S1D
      _PSW
      _PRW
    USB2
      _ADR
      BAR0
      [ ]
      USBW
      [ ]
      _S4D
      _S3D
      _S2D
      _S1D
      _PSW
      _PRW
    USB3
      _ADR
      BAR0
      [ ]
      USBW
      [ ]
      _S4D
      _S3D
      _S2D
      _S1D
      _PSW
      _PRW
    USB4
      _ADR
      BAR0
      [ ]
      USBW
      [ ]
      _S4D
      _S3D
      _S2D
      _S1D
      _PSW
      _PRW
      _STA
    USB5
      _ADR
      BAR0
      [ ]
      USBW
      [ ]
      _S4D
      _S3D
      _S2D
      _S1D
      _PSW
      _PRW
    USB6
      _ADR
      BAR0
      [ ]
      USBW
      [ ]
      _S4D
      _S3D
      _S2D
      _S1D
      _PSW
      _PRW
    HPET
      *HID
      CRS*
      HCNT
      [ ]
      HPTS
      [ ]
      HPTE
      _STA
      _CRS
    *INI
    CRS*
    MIN5
    MAX5
    LEN5
    MIN6
    MAX6
    LEN6
    _CRS
    _OSC
    GFX0
      _ADR
      OPBS
      OPBA
      _ROM
      IGDP
      [ ]
      [ ]
      [ ]
      GIVD
      [ ]
      GUMA
      [ ]
      [ ]
      GMFN
      [ ]
      [ ]
      CDCT
      [ ]
      [ ]
      GSSE
      GSSB
      GSES
      [ ]
      ASLS
      M512
      M1GB
      IGDM
      [ ]
      SIGN
      SIZE
      OVER
      SVER
      VVER
      GVER
      MBOX
      [ ]
      KSV0
      KSV1
      [ ]
      IBTT
      IPSC
      IPAT
      IBIA
      IBLC
      ITVF
      ITVM
      IDVM
      IDVS
      ISSC
      [ ]
      DRDY
      CSTS
      CEVT
      [ ]
      DIDL
      DDL2
      DDL3
      DDL4
      DDL5
      DDL6
      DDL7
      DDL8
      CPDL
      CPL2
      CPL3
      CPL4
      CPL5
      CPL6
      CPL7
      CPL8
      CADL
      CAL2
      CAL3
      CAL4
      CAL5
      CAL6
      CAL7
      CAL8
      NADL
      NDL2
      NDL3
      NDL4
      NDL5
      NDL6
      NDL7
      NDL8
      ASLP
      TIDX
      CHPD
      CLID
      CDCK
      SXSW
      EVTS
      CNOT
      NRDY
      [ ]
      SCIE
      GEFC
      GXFC
      GESF
      [ ]
      PARM
      DSLP
      [ ]
      ARDY
      ASLC
      TCHE
      ALSI
      BCLP
      PFIT
      CBLV
      BCLM
      CPFM
      EPFM
      [ ]
      GVD1
      TCOI
      [ ]
      [ ]
      [ ]
      SCIS
      [ ]
      DBTB
      GSCI
      GBDA
      SBCB
      OPTS
      OWAK
    MCHP
    [ ]
    [ ]
    TASM
    [ ]
  BN00
  SLPS
  PMS0
  [ ]
  [ ]
  RTCS
  [ ]
  PEXS
  WAKS
  [ ]
  PWBT
  [ ]
  GPE0
  [ ]
  [ ]
  PMES
  [ ]
  SLPB
    _HID
    _STA
    _PRW
  PWRB
    _HID
    _UID
    _STA
  BUFA
  IRA0
  LNKA
    _HID
    _UID
    _STA
    _PRS
    _DIS
    _CRS
    _SRS
  LNKB
    _HID
    _UID
    _STA
    _PRS
    _DIS
    _CRS
    _SRS
  LNKC
    _HID
    _UID
    _STA
    _PRS
    _DIS
    _CRS
    _SRS
  LNKD
    _HID
    _UID
    _STA
    _PRS
    _DIS
    _CRS
    _SRS
  LNKE
    _HID
    _UID
    _STA
    _PRS
    _DIS
    _CRS
    _SRS
  LNKF
    _HID
    _UID
    _STA
    _PRS
    _DIS
    _CRS
    _SRS
  LNKG
    _HID
    _UID
    _STA
    _PRS
    _DIS
    _CRS
    _SRS
  LNKH
    _HID
    _UID
    _STA
    _PRS
    _DIS
    _CRS
    _SRS
  RMEM
    _HID
    _UID
  SMIR
  [ ]
  [ ]
  [ ]
  SE__
  [ ]
  [ ]
  SS__
  ITKS
  ITKW
  RMHC
  [ ]
  RMHD
  [ ]
*SI*
*TZ*
_REV
*OS*
_OSI
*GL*
SP1O
IOCE
IOCL
SI1P
PEBS
PEBL
VTDS
VTDL
TCBR
TCLT
SRCB
SRCL
SUSW
PMBS
PMLN
SMIP
APCB
APCL
PM30
SMBS
SMBL
HPTB
HPTC
GPBS
GPLN
ACPH
ASSB
AOTB
AAXB
PEHP
SHPC
PEPM
PEER
PECS
TOBS
SUCC
NVLD
CRIT
NCRT
LDST
VRBS
IGDS
ITKE
RMHR
RRIO
RDMA
PICM
*PIC
OSVR
OSFL
MCTH
PRWP
GPRW
WAKP
DEB0
[ ]
DBG8
DEB1
[ ]
DBG9
SS1*
SS2_
SS3_
SS4_
IOST
TOPM
ROMS
MG1B
MG1L
MG2B
MG2L
KBFG
MSFG
FZTF
[ ]
PIRA
PIRB
PIRC
PIRD
[ ]
PIRE
PIRF
PIRG
PIRH
PSTE
TSTE
WOTB
WSSB
WAXB
_PTS
_WAK
OMSC
  _HID
  _UID
ASLA
PVID
*S0*
*S1*
*S3*
*S4*
*S5*
PTS_
WAK_

Comment: First thoughts: overheating, loose connection inside the case, insufficient power supply, or faulty hardware.  Is it a new computer?  Did you build it yourself?  What hardware changes have you made to your computer recently?

Comment: It is not new, it has 1 year and a few months. No HW changes since I bought it.

Comment: PSU spec, pls, and results of CPUID Hardware monitor for temps? PS - when I had same (by description) problem, I had to replace (*very old*) PSU

Comment: I will disassembly it in the weekend for cleaning and grab the SPU specs. Thanks

Comment: Added power data and HW monitor data

Answer (score 1):

Start with general maintenance.  Dust collects and can cause heat buildup.  Connectors being heated and cooled daily eventually work themselves loose.

1. Touch a metalic part of the case to disipate static electricity in your body.
2. Pull the power cable out of the case.
3. Open the case.
4. Clean out all of the dust with a 1 cm paint brush and/or gentle vacuum cleaner (standard hose vacuum on minimum setting or a hand-held vacuum.)
5. Locate each circuit board and cable.  Carefully remove each and plug it straight back in again firmly (not forcibly.)
6. Put the case back on.

Comment: I will try the maintance to see if it helps. Thanks

Comment: Have done the steps you sugested. Waiting to see if it will become stable. Thanks